# Powershell Get-Eventlog object output issue

Tags: string, powershell, object, output

I have an issue with using output of a variable as an input in my script.

When i run this :

```
$listoflogs = Get-EventLog -List | Select "Log"


$listoflogss | % { Get-EventLog -LogName $_ | Where-Object {$_.EntryType -Match "Error"} }
```

I got the following error, which i understand that it doesnt deal with the objects as an input.

```
Get-EventLog : The event log '@{Log=System}' on computer '.' does not exist. At line:5 char:31
+ $listoflogs | % { Get-EventLog <<<<  -LogName $_ | Where-Object {$_.EntryType -Match "Error"} }
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-EventLog], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetEventLogCommand
Get-EventLog : The event log '@{Log=ThinPrint Diagnostics}' on computer '.' does not exist. At line:5 char:31
+ $listoflogs | % { Get-EventLog <<<<  -LogName $_ | Where-Object {$_.EntryType -Match "Error"} }
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-EventLog], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetEventLogCommand
Get-EventLog : The event log '@{Log=Windows PowerShell}' on computer '.' does not exist. At line:5 char:31
+ $listoflogs | % { Get-EventLog <<<<  -LogName $_ | Where-Object {$_.EntryType -Match "Error"} }
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-EventLog], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetEventLogCommand
```

Then i modified script that translates the object to string and still i am unable to get the output i wanted.

```
$listoflogs = Get-EventLog -List | Select "Log"

$listoflogss = ($listoflogs | Out-String)

$listoflogss | % { Get-EventLog -LogName $_ | Where-Object {$_.EntryType -Match "Error"} }

Get-EventLog : Event log names must consist of printable characters and cannot contain \, *, ?, or space s At line:7 char:32
+ $listoflogss | % { Get-EventLog <<<<  -LogName $_ | Where-Object {$_.EntryType -Match "Error"} }
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-EventLog], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetEventLogCommand
```

I dont know what i am doing wrong, is there a better of achiveing this task. Still, I wouldnt mind understanding this concept of translating the object output to readable string for a script.

Comment: Hi, try `$listoflogs = Get-EventLog -List | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Log`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of testing, I think I understand what you want to achieve:

```
Get-EventLog -List | ForEach-Object {

    $logName = $_.Log

    Get-EventLog $logName |
        Where-Object { $_.EntryType -Match "Error" } |
        Select-Object *, @{ n = "LogName"; e = { $logName } }
}
```

The `Select-Object` cmdlet allows you to create a property on the fly to display it (needed here to add the log name to the displayed results).

`*` means all the original properties, `n` and `e` are shorthands for `name` and `expression`, and describe the additional property we want. This is called a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx).

In your original code, `-ExpandProperty` helped because you were piping a collection of objects to `Get-EventLog` without specifying you were after the `Log` property. But `Select`ing a property also means you remove all the others from the objects you are collecting.

You could also have suppressed the error like this:

```
$listoflogss |
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-EventLog -LogName $_.Log |
        Where-Object { $_.EntryType -Match "Error" }
    }
```

Comment: sodawillow: You Sir, are a genius. This is exectly what i was looking for but on top, your solution provides felxibilty to either provide all properties or i can pick and choose what i want to see. So, thank you very much for this and also for explaining what it each bit does. 

Just last thing, you can either point me to a website or you can explain this to me and i would be very glad.

can you please tell me what the following bit does...
@{ n = "LogName"; e = { $logName } }

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

try Something like this

```
  Get-EventLog -list | where {$_.Entries.Count -gt 0} | %{ $_.Entries } | where EntryType -EQ "Error"
```

Comment: -Expandproperty seems to be working but the output doesnt tell me which error belongs to to which log. for example the output i am after is LogName: Application, EntryType, Time etc... unfortunatly, all i get is big list of errors which belongs to different logs.

Esperento57: Sorry, it doesnt produce anything and i am still trying to figure out, how it would work for case. $_Entries.Count???? maybe i am missing something

Comment: `Get-EventLog -List` lists the `Log`s, then you have to run `Get-EventLog` again for each `Log` to get the events.

Comment: if you dont test "$_.Entries.Count -gt 0" you will be error when not entry exist in categorie. of log. I have modified my code